# Notes XPages typeahead returns some of names with box brackets

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I setup typeahead in XPages and refer ($PeopleGroupsFlat) view. However some of the returned values are surrounded with Brackets.

For example,
In view the names are listed as below.

```
 Test, Admin
 Test, User
```

In tyeahead list appears as below.

```
 Test, Admin
 [Test, User]
```

Why does this happen? Is it related to 'Alternate name'? I set alternate name for 'Test User' but not 'Test Admin'. If so, what setting remove the brackets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume, but I'm not sure, that you refer to a column that contains multiple values. The brackets are the result of a conversion from a Vector or ArrayList to a String. You might have to change the code, or use a different column, or a different view.